# How to translate this 点だった知識が線につながることを経験していただけたら幸いです

Tags: conditionals, subjects, object

How should I interpret this?

> 点だった知識が線につながることを経験していただけたら幸いです

In my mind,  mostly it seems like, based on -tara:

If 《 condition 》, then you are fortunate.
Or: when 《 condition 》, I am fortunate.

On the other hand, I've also thought of it as, in a literal translation:
When you have come to experience the point of knowledge as connected by the line,  you are fortunate.

Google translate gives:
I hope you will experience that the knowledge that was a point leads to a line.

Is there a different reading to 幸いです?

Also should I view koto as こと( 点だった知識が線につながる) or こと(線につながる)? As in,  to what extent does koto nominalise the phrase?

Comment: Welcome to JLSE! Unfortunately, as stated, this question is likely "off-topic", as it is a translation question that demonstrates arguably no prior research effort. Please see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Therefore, please could you edit your question to include your attempt at the translation, and explain which bit specifically you are having trouble with? This way, it will less likely be deemed off-topic. The reason behind this rule is that Stack Exchange wishes to help people (you, and others reading your question) learn, instead of being a free translation service.

Answer (score 2):

～たら幸い【さいわい】です (or ～れば幸いです) literally means "it's fortunate if ～". But you should memorize this as a common set phrase that is usually translated into English as "I would appreciate if ～" or something along these lines. It is one of the politest ways to request  something in Japanese, and people use this phrase mainly in business letters and formal invitations.

Google Translate's result ("I hope you will ～") is also correct, although it's a bit simplified.

Comment: Sasuga !!!!!!!!